# How to implement nested navigation in a Two Pane layout in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation, adaptive-layout

I'm developing an app with a Settings-like screen using Jetpack Compose, that adapts to different screen sizes. The app  incorporates a `NavGraph` which has a top-level screen containing a `LazyColumn`. Clicking on an item in the `LazyColumn` takes the user to different destinations within the `NavGraph`. The destinations themselves can be graphs containing multiple screens, nested inside the top-level navigation component.

For small screen devices, I use a `NavHost` to navigate from the top-level screen to various nested screens. A typical nested navigation on mobile would look like this:
[image: Mobile Navigation]

However, for large screen devices, I would like to use a Two Pane layout, with the `LazyColumn` positioned in the left pane and the selected destination in the right pane. The destinations may further lead to additional screens, which would open in the right pane of the Two Pane layout. Something like this:
[image: Tablet Navigation]

Initially, I tried using separate `NavHost`s for each screen size, with one containing the top-level screen and the other without it. This would allow using one `NavHost` for small screen devices and the other `NavHost` to be embedded in the right pane on large screen devices. However, managing and synchronizing the open screens between the two hosts would be overly complex and impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to accomplish this with the help of this video: [Navigation Compose on every screen](https://youtu.be/LTLQhC6VadI).

To achieve such a behavior, two `NavHost`s are required. One would be top-level and the other would be inside the `NestedScreen`. The top-level `NavHost` would look something like this:

```kotlin
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "topLevelRoute") {
    composable("topLevelRoute") { 
        TopLevelRoute(isExpandedWindowSize = isExpandedWindowSize, selectedItemId = selectedItemId)
    }

    composable("nestedScreen1") { NestedScreen1(...) }
    composable("nestedScreen2") { NestedScreen2(...) }
    ...
}
```

The `TopLevelRoute` composable with a `TwoPane` (available in Accompanist library) would look something like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TopLevelRoute(
    isExpandedWindowSize: Boolean, 
    selectedItemId: String?,
) {
    if (isExpandedWindowSize) {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        TwoPane(
            first = { TopLevelScreen(...) },
            second = {
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "nestedScreen1") {
                    composable("nestedScreen1") { NestedScreen1(...) }
                    composable("nestedScreen2") { NestedScreen2(...) }
                    ...
                }
            },
            ...
    } else {
        TopLevelScreen(...)
    }
}
```

Now, on a small screen device, when the user clicks on an item in the `LazyColumn`, we can navigate to the nested screen using the top-level `navController` while on a large screen device, we can navigate using the `navController` that is inside the `TopLevelRoute`.